# Why can I not change a html element with JS?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to get a JS script to insert HMTL on a python flask server and it doesn't seem to want to run.

File Structure:

```
project
  static
    css
      style.css
  templates
    demo.html
    download.html
    index.html
    wrongLink.html
  main.py
```

Here is the flask code that runs the webserver:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file
from flask import request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('demo.html')
```

I also render some templates like this:

```
return render_template('download.html',
    thumb=thumb, title=title, options=options, counter=counter)
```

I realised that I'm having trouble specifically with one piece of JS in the download.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <form action="/getVideo" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Link" value="{{ Link }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Convert">
      </form>

      <img src="{{ thumb }}" alt="Thumbnail" width="480" height="270">
      <p>{{ title }}</P>
      <p id="demo"></p>

      <form id="options">
        <input type="submit" value="Download">
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.alert("JS works");
      var i;
      var options = JSON.parse{{options | tojson}};
      for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        out += '<input type="radio" value="' + options[i]["res"] += '"><br>';
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hi";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Neither the alert window or the element edit execute so I'm not sure what's happening there.

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes ? Can you check if you get any errors on the console ?

Comment: Like I said it works in some files or in some folders but not these ones and there aren't any console errors.

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one element with the id of "demo"?  Are the files identical but with just different names?

Comment: No, all the files are different and the "demo" id only appears once.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the problem.  You are saying the same files work when they are in the template directory, but not when in another directory?  You might want to add some additional html in each file, to indicate which file has been loaded, and an alert inside each script section to ensure it is being executed.

Comment: Can you add your flask application code ?

Comment: how about the js?

Comment: [RufusVS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925592/rufusvs) I meant that they don't work in the template directory but they do outside it. I'll try, is there any reason the JS wouldn't be executing? edit: I think it might just be because the JS isn't executing, it doesn't show alert boxes either.

Comment: Not enough information, you need post all the code or files then we can check for you.

Comment: It's just that one bit of is at the bottom that won't execute, I'll post more of that file and edit the question tomorrow.